# Keep my form above the taskbar?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My overall goal is to render a second (or third, fourth...) mouse cursor.  To this end, I have created a frameless, topmost, transparent window.  I can draw on this window (I have 4 buttons on it to show that it's properly covering the whole desktop) - but when I click on the taskbar, it is brought to the top and overlays my buttons and drawn line.

How can I keep my window *above* the taskbar?

Alternatively, is there a way that I can draw on the "final" version of the screen?

Here's the code from my .Designer.cs file:

```
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.None;
this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
this.CausesValidation = false;
this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(332, 332);
this.ControlBox = false;
this.Controls.Add(this.button4);
this.Controls.Add(this.button3);
this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
this.MaximizeBox = false;
this.MinimizeBox = false;
this.Name = "Screen";
this.ShowIcon = false;
this.SizeGripStyle = System.Windows.Forms.SizeGripStyle.Hide;
this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.WindowsDefaultBounds;
this.TopMost = true;
this.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.White;
```

Comment: Its really unclear. Kindly attach screenshots to help us understand it

Comment: Erm, wait, how did you click on the taskbar when the window covers the entire screen?  Assuming you managed to do this somehow, it is of course by design.

Comment: That's why I pasted to script that sets the form properties - those settings allow my form to not be displayed and to be "clicked-through"

Comment: My appologies to those who do not understand the question - but there were enough that *did* understand that I got useful tips from.  Besides which - I did find my answer (See my post below).

Comment: How can this be unclear?

Answer (score 2):

Without analysing the exact motivation of doing this and whether this approach is the best way through, you should note that the taskbar's behaviour is equivalent to the one of any other window: `TopMost` can be used without any restriction. On the other hand, it is considered outside the "WorkingArea" and thus, depending upon the properties you are using, it might be ignored. Take a look at the sample codes below to understand this better.

`Main Form` covering all the available space above the taskbar:

```
this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height);
this.Location = new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Left, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Top);
```

`Main Form` covering the whole available space of the screen:

```
this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
this.Location = new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Left, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Top);
```

Thus, you can locate your form on top of the taskbar without any problem by bearing the mind that it represents the difference between `WorkingArea` and `Bounds` of the screen.

CLARIFICATION: this answer highlights what might be the reason for the taskbar to be treated differently than any other part of the screen. It does not imply that you have to make your form as big as the whole screen to put it over the taskbar; you can put it over the taskbar whenever you want with an as small size as you wish. What you have to bear in mind is that `WorkingArea` does not provide the whole dimensions of the screen, but just the area ABOVE the taskbar; if you want to bring the taskbar into consideration, consider `Bounds`.

Comment: If you were analyzing my approach, what would you suggest be a better option?  I *am* implementing something that works like many mice at once, so I do need multiple "pointers".

Comment: @EarlB excuse me? Your approach? I didn't intend to comment your approach (because I am afraid that have quite a few problems); I did just answer the problem in this question: "Keep my form above the taskbar?" -> there is no restriction to put your form on the taskbar; my answer was just intending to explain the point graphically by highlighting the problem you most likely found (not too clear from your code); that is, relying on WorkingArea, instead on Bounds. Summary: this answer shows a point via example, point which apparently you didn't get.

Comment: sorry, didn't mean any offense.  Quite the opposite.  But I misread where you said "without analyzing ... whether this approach is the best way..." - which I read as meaning you had thoughts that it might not be the best way.  So I asked for what those thoughts might be.  I tend to take a "what I can make work" approach, *then* worry about "best approach".

Comment: @EarlB No problem. I cannot be sure about what might be the best approach without even knowing what you are after. But this thing of putting many forms in different places of the screen, sounds pretty problematic. In this question you were asking something very specific and I intended to solve it. If you are interested in something different; like knowing the best proceeding to account for certain situation, you would have to post a new question. In case of doing that, be as clear as possible about what you want, what you have tried, what is wrong with what you have tried, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'll go with varocarbas answer,but there is something that i want to add which i think might be useful.

A few things are there that i guess may be helpful,when i read your question the first idea that struck my mind was to create a `GlobalHook` to monitor message `WM_CBT`,this message is send to GlobalHook procedure when the system is about to `Maximize,Minimize,Restore or Focus` a Window.When any hook is trapped you can override any required events to block that window from becoming the topmost window,thus giving `your Form` a chance to remain the topmost Window.This method will be highly helpful if it worked as i am expecting.

If you are interested in this, here are the methods that are required to make a GlobalHook work.
[SetWindowsHookEx()](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetWindowsHookEx.html),used to tell the system to create a GlobalHook.
[HookProc](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Delegates/HookProc.html),Represents the method called when a hook catches a monitored event.
[HookType](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/HookType.html),Enumerates the valid hook types passed into a call to SetWindowsHookEx.
[CallNextHook](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/CallNextHookEx.html).If using interoperability is messy,try [this](http://mwinapi.sourceforge.net/) open source library that contains WindowsAPI functions in a managed wrapper.Hope this helps you,meanwhile i'm also trying to get the stuff working for you.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling for a few hours with this same problem. I thought of a nice solution: just change the bottom padding of the form dynamically whenever the form is maximized.

```
If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized then
    Dim pd As New Padding
    pd.Left = Me.Padding.Left
    pd.Right = Me.Padding.Right
    pd.Top = Me.Padding.Top
    pd.Bottom = Me.Height - Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height
    Me.Padding = pd
end if
```

This way the form is not above the taskbar, but at least your controls are!
Note: in designing your forms you can leave the bottom-padding 0.
If you want your form to be able to minimize/normal resize, then you may want to reset the bottom padding to 0 in another form event.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the solution about 15 minutes after I posted.  (Isn't that always the way?  Research for hours, but as soon as you ask for help, you figure it out on your own. :)

I have an event that is calling my code with position updates.  If I simply call "BringToFront" in this event, it works just fine.  The event is called many times per second, but if I throttle my behavior back to 1/4 second, it still works great.

Comment: Sorry to find problems in your solution but this has absolutely nothing to do with the fact of being on top of the taskbar or not. As explained in my answer; the taskbar is completely normal except for one issue: WorkingArea ignores it. This is most likely (not sure because your code does not show the problem) where you were doing things wrong and what you had to correct: if it topmost and you locate it properly (beyond workingarea), it would be topmost over the taskbar (bringtofront does not do anything; topmost is the "most powerful" alternative).

Comment: I guess I'm confusing "apparent" behavior with "actual" behavior.  My ultimate goal is to emulate a "mouse driver" for multiple mice.  The "above-the-taskbar" form is *purely* for drawing the curor*S*.  Since the form is "click-through", clicking on the taskbar raises it over my form - so the cursors can't be drawn.  My appologies for being unclear.